# filtering elastic search results by fields and values

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have a sample data that includes data from univerities, schools and dormitories.
I want to use this data in Elasticsearch. I send the body as follows when making filteration:

Sample Data:

```
[
    {
        name: 'Maisha school of sience',
        school_type: 'public',
        location: 'A',
    },
    {
        name: 'Maisha elementry school',
        school_type: 'private',
        location: 'B',
    },
    {
        name: 'istanbul university',
        university_type: 'public',
        location: 'C',
    },
    {
        name: 'Maisha university',
        university_type: 'private',
        location: 'D',
    },
    {
        name: 'kbb center of Maisha',
        dormitory_type: 'public',
        location: 'E',
    },
    {
        name: 'high Maisha dorm',
        dormitory_type: 'private',
        location: 'F',
    },
]
```

My Query:

```
"query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "*Maisha*",
                        "fields": [
                            "name"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "school_type": "public"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Result:

```
{
   name: 'Maisha school of sience',
   school_type: 'public',
   location: 'A',
}
```

This result actually makes sence because it gives the exact result but dormitory and university data are not shown which is the main problem. In other words, I only want the **school_type** to be **public** but why it filters out and not showing university and dormitory data?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost correct, you just need to change `must` in `bool` to `should`. I just indexed your sample data and using below query.

**Sample documents**

```
{
        "name": "Maisha school of sience",  // doc-1
        "school_type": "public",
        "location": "A"
}
{
        "name": "istanbul university", // doc-2
        "university_type": "public",
        "location": "C"
}
{
        "name": "Maisha university", // so on
        "university_type": "private",
        "location": "D"
}
{
        "name": "kbb center of Maisha",
        "dormitory_type": "public",
        "location": "E"
}
{
        "name": "high Maisha dorm",
        "dormitory_type": "private",
        "location": "F"
}
```

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [. ->> notice should clause here
                {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "*Maisha*",
                        "fields": [
                            "name"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "school_type": "public"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

it returns below result, hope you are looking for the same output.

```
{
    "took": 12,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 4,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 1.287682,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "71296703",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1.287682,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "Maisha school of sience",
                    "school_type": "public",
                    "location": "A"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "71296703",
                "_id": "3",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "Maisha university",
                    "university_type": "private",
                    "location": "D"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "71296703",
                "_id": "4",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "kbb center of Maisha",
                    "dormitory_type": "public",
                    "location": "E"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "71296703",
                "_id": "5",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "high Maisha dorm",
                    "dormitory_type": "private",
                    "location": "F"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am trying to follow this in my data which is big but it gives me results that I dont even search for.

Comment: I can provide my query if you wish

Comment: You can check from here: http://egitim.ankageo.com/api/records?q=besiktas&yurt_type=Devlet

Comment: while, q is the searched text and yurt_type=Devlet means dormitory type is public.

Comment: @Angels Sorry for the delay in response, could you share the mapping of your index?

Comment: @Angels also one more thing, which I noticed is that query result you shared, has only one type, while sample documents you shared has `university_type`, `school_type`, `dormitory_type`. I'll update answer with the sample documents I used to get your expected results.

Comment: @Angels but your query results doesn't match with the input data types, please check my comment where I mentioned about the type and try to create the index with my sample data and lmk if its not correct

Comment: I am sorry. I was first learning how to do it on a sample data. Now when I try on real data it doesnt work. I am sharing my codes in a moment.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/Qn77KQ

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242538/discussion-between-amit-and-angels).